# Отделить часть от response

Tags: python

есть такой response:

```
KQ75 . . . tr5d7d0d347a765
```

Мне нужно отделить все,что идет после KQ75.Проблема еще в том,что после KQ75 всегда разные символы.Но есть другой response.В нем лежит только KQ75.Мне необходимо их сравнить.Как то возможно?

Answer (score 0):

Регулярные выражения?

```
import re
result = re.split(r'KQ75', '. . . tr5d7d0d347a765')
```

Результат:

```
['. . . tr5d7d0d347a765']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'KQ75.......5h1j2v5jjh'
b = a[0:4]
print(b)
>>> KQ75
```

Это ЕСЛИ нужно только KQ75
Если же только то, что после KQ75, то:

```
a='KQ75.....grsgrgsrg'
b=a[4:]
print(b)
>>> .....grsgrgsrg
```

Также есть регулярные выражения

И если тебе их нужно сравнить, то смотря как
Если просто сравнить, то:

```
a='KQ75....trgsrgsdg'
b='KQ75....fsdjfsjfhsj'
c=a[4:]
d=b[4:]
if c==d:
    print("Совпадают")
```

Но это все методы джуна. Так что учись использовать регулярки